# Read image data into R piece-by-piece

Tags: r, image

I'm working with some fairly large image files (aerial survey mosaics, generally > 1 billion pixels), such that loading an entire image into memory would be a problem on my system. I would like to bring them into R piece-by-piece, such that I can process them in "grid-wise" sections.

NOTE: I'm not tied to a particular image format, so `tiff`, `png`, `bmp` etc would all be fine as inputs.

I can do something along these lines with `readJPEG`, but this requires loading the entire file into memory first, so it doesn't really solve my problem, but hopefully shows what I'm trying to achieve.

```
image.file <- "~/Desktop/penguins.jpg"

grid.size <- 100
v <- 3
h <- 1

library( jpeg )
image <- readJPEG( image.file )[ seq.int( (v-1)*grid.size+1, (v)*grid.size, 1 ),
                                 seq.int( (h-1)*grid.size+1, h*grid.size, 1 ), ]
```

The above loads in only a sample of the image, designated by `grid.size`, `v`, and `h`, such that it would be easy to build this into a loop to analyse an image in sections.

Is it possible to achieve this *without* loading the entire image into memory? Something like `read.csv`, making use of the `skip` and `n` parameters would be reasonable (it would at least only load the vertical sections one at a time, so much less memory needed than `readJPEG`).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you have ImageMagick installed, you can [crop the image from the command line](http://www.imagemagick.org/Usage/files/#massive) before reading it into R. An example using this image: http://www.worldatlas.com/worldmaps/worldpoliticallarge.jpg

To create the cropped image:

```
x <- 800  ## x and y are offsets
y <- 400
w <- 200  ## width and height of cropped image
h <- 100
filename <- "worldpoliticallarge.jpg"
outname <- "crop.jpg"
cmd <- sprintf("jpegtran -crop %dx%d+%d+%d -copy none %s > %s", w, h, x, y, filename, outname)
system(cmd)
```

Check to see if the new image contains the region we want:

```
library(jpeg)
original <- readJPEG(filename)
cropped <- readJPEG(outname)
all.equal(original[(y+1):(y+h), (x+1):(x+w), ], cropped)
# [1] TRUE
```

Comment: Great idea. I'll have to test the memory load when ImageMagick is doing the crop. Do you know whether it loads the whole image into memory for the crop?

Comment: I've done some tests, and this solution works really well! However, it does seem to load the entire image into memory (for an 8E8 pixel jpg image, cropping a 200x100 section, it loaded 3.4GB into RAM). Nevertheless, it's much more manageable than loading into R as an array, so I'm accepting the answer. If anyone has a solution with lower memory usage (ImageMagick docs suggest it can do it, but I'm not convinced yet), I'd really appreciate that too. Thank you very much @WeihuanWong!

Comment: When it comes to memory consumption, the solution based on **RBioFormats**  seems to be more efficient: I was able to iterate over the image in 1000 x 1000 pieces without exceeding 0.5GB of memory usage at any given time.

Comment: Great to know @aoles. Thank you for going to the trouble of testing

Answer (score 4):

You can easily achieve this entirely in R for almost any image format with the help of **[RBioFormats](https://github.com/aoles/RBioFormats)**, which can be obtained from GitHub.

```
devtools::install_github("aoles/RBioFormats")
```

The chunk size can be specified in the `subset` argument to `read.image()`. The following example illustrates how to process an image piece-wise without ever loading the whole file into memory.

```
library(RBioFormats)

filename <- system.file("images", "sample-color.png", package="EBImage")

## first, get image dimensions from metadata
meta <- coreMetadata(read.metadata(filename))

xdim <- meta$sizeX
ydim <- meta$sizeY

## set chunk size
chunksize <- 300  

## itarate over image chunks row-wise
for(i in 1:ceiling(ydim/chunksize)) {
  for(j in 1:ceiling(xdim/chunksize)) {
    x1 <- (j-1) * chunksize + 1
    x2 <- min( j * chunksize, xdim )
    y1 <- (i-1) * chunksize + 1
    y2 <- min( i * chunksize, ydim )

    cat(sprintf("[%d:%d, %d:%d] ", x1, x2, y1, y2))

    img <- read.image(filename, subset = list(X=x1:x2, Y=y1:y2))

    ## perform the actual image processing
    ## here we just print the min and max pixel intensities
    cat(range(img), "\n")        
  }
}
```

You might also want to check out **[EBImage](http://www.bioconductor.org/packages/EBImage)**, an image processing toolbox for R. It provides functionality to view images and perform various transformations and filtering.

Comment: Thanks for the response! This looks like a great solution, except it doesn't seem to work for very large images. I can run the `img <-...` line for a small jpg, but when I try to pass a large (8E8 pixels) one, I get an error `Error in .jcall(reader, "I", "getSeriesCount") : 
  java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Array size > Integer.MAX_VALUE!`. Maybe a size limitation?

Comment: I see - would it be possible that you share the particular file which triggeres the error so that I could debug it?

Comment: Sure. I've just shared a file with you on DropBox, using your email listed in the "EBImage" `DESCRIPTION` file. Please don't distribute the image, but I'm more than happy for you to use it for debugging.

Comment: It looks like a limitation on the integer class in java (maxing out a little over 2E8). Maybe change the "I" (line 214 of read.image.R on github) to a "J" to use a long value instead of an integer?

Comment: github seems like a better place to discuss. I've opened an issue there.